# Freeing array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'm trying to free an array of structures, which inside holds an array of strings, which they are all allocated with malloc and the program works until I try to free it with the function I made , and I get core dumped.

this is my structures:
name-allocated array ,courses -array of strings , and teach is an allocated array of structures which I'm trying to free one by one.

```
 struct date

{
    int day,month,year;
};
struct lecturer
{
char * name;
struct date birthdate;
int num_of_courses;
char ** courses;
};
```

this is my function:

```
void freeAndExit(struct lecturer* teach,int num)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=ZERO;i<num;i++)
  {
    free(teach[i]->name);
    for(j=ZERO;j<teach[i]->num_of_courses;j++)
        free(teach[i]->courses[j]);
  }

free (teach[i]);
}
```

this is how I call my function from my main()

```
freeAndExit(&teach,numTeach);
```

any ideas?
Edit:
this is How I inputed my structs

```
void InputLecturer(struct lecturer** teach,int num)
{
    int i;
    char temp[SIZE];
    getchar();
  teach=(struct lecturer*)malloc(sizeof(struct lecturer)*num);
   for(i=ZERO;i<num;i++)
   {
     printf("Please enter the lecturers name:\n");
     InputStr(temp);
     (*teach)[i].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp));
     strcpy((*teach)[i].name,temp);
     printf("Please enter the birtday date:|Day|Month|Year|\n");
     scanf(" %d %d %d",&(*teach)[i].birthdate.day,&(*teach)[i].birthdate.month,&(*teach)[i].birthdate.year);
     printf("Enter the number of courses\n");
     scanf("%d",&(*teach)[i].num_of_courses);
     getchar();
     InputCourses(&(*teach)[i],(*teach)[i].num_of_courses);

   }


}
void InputCourses(struct lecturer* teach,int num)
{
    int i;
    char temp[SIZE];
   teach->courses=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*num);
   for(i=ZERO;i<num;i++)
   {
      printf("Please enter course name number %d\n",i+1);
      InputStr(temp);
      teach->courses[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp));
      strcpy(teach->courses[i],temp);
   }

}
```

Comment: Although this could be due to a number of things, I would start with the way you allocated these `struct`s. Could you edit the question to show the allocations?

Comment: OT: but replacing '0' by fancy stuff like `ZERO` is pointless add only adds confusion. You mean "zero", then write `0`.

Comment: I edited and Inputted structs, ZERO is a requirement for my project by the instructor.. long story .

Comment: @AlexAlex How is `teach` declared and used in `main` before you call `freeAndExit(&teach,numTeach);`?  Are you sure you're not taking the address of a pointer, and ending up with a `struct lecturer **`?  Did you mean to just do `freeAndExit(teach, numTeach)`?  Also you do `free(teach[i]);` in `freeAndExit`, but `teach[i]` would give you a `struct teacher`, not a `struct teacher *`.  Should that be just `free(teach);`?

Comment: Are you sure this code even compiles? There are lots of obvious problems eg `(teach)[i].name` in `InputLecturer` which should be `(*teach)[i].name`

Comment: `free (teach[i]);` is outside the `i` loop, so the allocated memory is never freed - but you then try to free memory at an invalid array element, after the `i` loop.

Comment: @Chris Turner the teach[i].name is a string, why would It have 2 stars? and the code compiles in ubuntu and prints.

Comment: @Weather Vane you are right! I didn't see that!, thank you!

Comment: @AlexAlex because `teach` is a `struct lecturer **` and more importantly, you have it exactly the way I said it should be on the next line!

Comment: @ChrisTurner my bad, I copied it without the *, I have it right as you said in my code, sorry for the confusion and thank you

Comment: lol - get a different instructor, that ZERO thing is ridiculous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this line is outside of the loop so the value of `i` would be outside the bounds allocated for `teach`. Secondly, `teach[i]` is a `struct lecturer` - so it's not allocated memory anyway, so nothing to free.

```
free (teach[i]);
```

What is needing to be freed is `teach` itself so replace the above line with this one.

```
free (teach);
```

You should also make sure you allocate enough memory for any strings - they always need one more than you think you need to store the terminating NUL character. So, for example, this line

```
teach->courses[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(temp));
```

should be

```
teach->courses[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp)+1));
```

(note: you shouldn't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C)

Not allocating enough space for the string invokes undefined behaviour as when you `strcpy` the string into the newly allocated memory, the NUL terminating character is going to be written beyond the bounds of memory you've been allocated and which could be later overwritten by some legitimate owner.

Alternatively you could combine the `malloc` and `strcpy` calls into one call to `strdup` which allocates the right amount of memory and copies the existing string for you...

```
teach->courses[i]=strdup(temp);
```

Comment: No, I'm not saying that `free(teach[i]);` should be moved inside the loop - I'm saying it shouldn't even exist

Comment: Chirs, my bad. I overlook the declaration of `teach` as a simple array rather than a pointer-to-pointer. You are correct. (and already had my vote, so I can't vote twice)